# file_get_contents not working in wayfair page

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

i am having a problem with PHP file_get_contents.i am trying to fetch inforamtion following url but is getting captcha page.

```
  $link = 'http://www.wayfair.com/a/product_review_page/get_update_reviews_json?_format=json&product_sku=KUS1523&page_number=5&sort_order=relevance&filter_rating=&filter_tag=&item_per_page=5';
  $Page_information = file_get_contents($link);
  print_r($Page_information);
```

Also i am trying to get page information using php curl but same captcha page is display.

```
            $cookie='cookie.txt';
            if(!file_exists($cookie)){
                    $fh = fopen($cookie, "w");
                    fwrite($fh, "");
                    fclose($fh);
            }
            $ch = curl_init();  
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);   
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.wayfair.com/a/product_review_page/get_update_reviews_json?_format=json&product_sku=KUS1523&page_number=5&sort_order=relevance&filter_rating=&filter_tag=&item_per_page=5");  
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);   
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,1);         
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);      
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
                $result11 = curl_exec($ch);   
               print_r($result11);
```

Comment: as a first guess I would say that you should add a useragent to either the `file_get_contents` ( context arg ) or the `curl` request

Comment: @RamRaider i have added user agent but this is not working

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36");  // user_agent is missing.. i tested you curl example and with CURLOPT_USERAGENT works

Comment: @CatalinB i have added this code but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you analyze the headers from a browser where cookies and javascript are disabled you should see the bare minimum sent - some, perhaps all might be required and are set with the context argument.

```
/* set the options for the stream context */
$args=array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => array(
                'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0',
                'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Host: www.wayfair.com',
                'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'
            )
        )
    );
/* create the context */
$context=stream_context_create( $args );
$link = 'http://www.wayfair.com/a/product_review_page/get_update_reviews_json?_format=json&product_sku=KUS1523&page_number=5&sort_order=relevance&filter_rating=&filter_tag=&item_per_page=5';

/* Get the response from remote url */
$res = file_get_contents( $link, FILE_TEXT, $context );

/* process the response */
print_r( $res );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://www.wayfair.com/a/product_review_page/get_update_reviews_json?_format=json&product_sku=KUS1523&page_number=5&sort_order=relevance&filter_rating=&filter_tag=&item_per_page=5";
$cookie = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookie.txt';

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,1);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

//added
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36");

$result11 = curl_exec($ch);   
print_r($result11);
```

try this

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /distil_r_captcha.html was not found on this server.  showing this error

Comment: C:\php>php test.php
{"all_modern_sidebar":false,"create_review_button":{"btn_arrow":true,"title":"Wri

Comment: catalinB  i can't understand what you are writeing

Comment: reponse of running test.php